# Cannot Add new row to database with DataAdapter.insertCommand vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I try to add new record to the database with command DataAdapter.InsertCommand. But I don't know why It doesn't insert new record to database

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Dim cnn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\1_Project\Project_of_VB_Net\AccessDatabase\StudentDatabase.accdb"
    cmd.Connection = cnn
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StudentData(StudentID) VALUES (@studentid)"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid", "123")
    Try
        cnn.Open()
        da.InsertCommand  = cmd
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cnn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Please help me find out what's wrong with it?

Comment: You need to execute the query.  `AddWithValue` is sub-optimal especially if `StudentId` is a number (`"123"` is not).  But why are you inserting Ids?  Thats the DB's job.

Comment: @Plutonix I think that does da.insertcommand=cmd that mean "execute the query"? StudentID field is a text when i declare in database. i insert IDs because I would like when i click button add, it willl create a new row which have a ID first (ID is a text and is put from textbox)

Comment: I have never used a data adapter like you have and I don't see how it would work.  Either use the command directly without an adapter (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()) or configure your dataadaptor with the insert command, map the parameter to your studentid field, and then insert the record to your datatable and run da.Update(dt)

Comment: @HaimKatz Hi katz, I found the solution for my problem and update above . Thank you so much for your help :)

Comment: Don't put answers in the question.  Just post your own answer below and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm all in favor of using what works and I see the solution above works.  The advantage of using a dataadapter however, is that it wraps all the sql commands needed for the CRUD operations of the datatable.  You can configure your own commands or let visual studio configure them automatically by using a sqlcommandbuilder.  Then once you have the adapter configured all you need to do is something like this

```
    Dim myds As New DataSet()
    Dim mytable as New datatable()
    myds.Tables.Add(mytable)
    Dim myconstr As String = "ConnectionStringtoDataBase"
    Dim myconn As New SqlConnection(myconstr)

    Dim da as new SqlDataAdapter( “SELECT * FROM StudentTable”,cnn)
    Dim mycb As New SqlCommandBuilder(da)
    da.Fill(mytable)
    Dim myrow As DataRow = mytable.NewRow()
    myrow("ID") = "thestudentid"
    myrow("StudentName") = "John doe"
    myrow("StudentID") = 12345
    myrow("StudentClass") = "VB 101"
    mytable.Rows.Add(myrow)
    da.Update(mytable)
```

The CommandBuilder will automatically add insert, update and delete commands to the dataadapter (if your select command is one table only, otherwise you'll have to configure it manually).

Comment: It's seem to be a good idea to try. But could you please tell me more detail about it? How can I have the adapter configured. I tried with your part (Comment everything just except your part which you said) but I think it's not enough and it say error. COuld you please give an example or somthing

Comment: I have updated my answer.  My previous answer confused the tableadapter with the dataadapter.  Truth is I haven't used a datadapter for quite a while, I find using typed datasets and the tableadapter much easier and helps prevent programming mistakes.  If you are unfamiliar with them look them up in msdn.  Once you start with them you won't go back to untyped datasets.